# Inner join for a single table - mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

coaches( coach_code, coach_name, year_of_birth)

I need to create a query that returns pairs of coaches that were born at the same year and the year. every pair should appear only once. (coach 1, coach 2,year_of_birth)

the problem is that it's the same table and the inner join doesn't work.

any suggestions ?

Comment: Inner joins with the same table work just fine. Just give them aliases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT c1.coach_code AS coach1, c2.coach_code AS coach2, c1.year_of_birth
FROM coaches AS c1
JOIN coaches AS c2 ON c1.year_of_birth = c2.year_of_birth AND c1.coach_code < c2.coach_code
```

Comment: From where did come c1 and c2 ?

Comment: They're the aliases assigned in the `FROM` and `JOIN` clauses.

Comment: shouldn't you write FROM coaches AS c1 ?

Comment: The `AS` keyword is optional.

Comment: but.. I think you might get the same pairs in different order.. no ?

Comment: No, look at the comparison of coach codes. It will always be `coach1` less then `coach2`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `GROUP_CONCAT` but keep in mind there is limit of characters in GROUP_CONCAT

```
SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(coach_name SEPARATOR ',') as `pair`,year_of_birth
FROM coaches
GROUP BY year_of_birth
```

[**GROUP_CONCAT(expr)**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat)

Comment: If there are 3 or more coaches with the same birth year, this will combine all of them. He wants pairs.